# Sine and limits

Tags: limits

So I have to show that the function, f(x)= cot(x)-1/x, is decreasing in the interval
(nπ,(n+1)π). It says I need to use the inequality |sin(x)|<|x| for x≠0

So I know that a function is decreasing if f'(x)<0 in the given interval. So I have found the derivative of the function to be f'(x)=-1/sin(x)+1/x^2

However, I don't understand how I can use this to prove the inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that $f'(x)=-\dfrac1{\sin^{\color{red}2}(x)}+\dfrac1{x^2}$. And\begin{align}f'(x)<0&\iff-\dfrac1{\sin^2(x)}+\dfrac1{x^2}<0\\&\iff\frac1{x^2}<\frac1{\sin^2(x)}\\&\iff\sin^2(x)<x^2\\&\iff|\sin x|<|x|.\end{align}